# Error al consumir WS SOAP desde ORACLE

Tags: webservice, soap, oracle-11g

tengo ORACLE 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 y estoy intentando consumir un Web Service SOAP desde oracle con el siguiente codigo

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WS (DATAI NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS

   err_num             NUMBER;
   err_msg             VARCHAR2 (255);
   WSDL                UTL_HTTP.req;
   RESP                UTL_HTTP.resp;
```

pero me esta devolviendo el siguiente error

```
[Error] PLS-00201 (8: 24): PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_HTTP' must be declared
```

ya ejecute el comando

```
grant execute on UTL_HTTP to miUsuario;
```

el webservide que quiero consumir se encuentra en localhost.

AYUDAAA!!!

Comment: Ya creastes las `ACL` ? El usuario con el que creas la funcion es el mismo con los permisos?

Comment: aun no e creado las ACL, tu me podrías decir como se crean?